# Keyword search in Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I’m curious to learn if the ability to do a free text search across sets/charts exists in apache superset. How would I do this today?

Comment: General software use is not on-topic here. Please review the [help] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of superset, refer to the snapshot below on how to access the search field.

[image]